# Flutter – MultiBlocProvider doesn't instantiate BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

So I have this code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<ProfilePageBloc>(
        create: (context) => ProfilePageBloc(userRepository: UserRepository.instance),
      ),
      BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
        create: (context) => HomeBloc(),
      ),
    ],
    child: BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
            builder: (context, state) {

              if (state is StateThatDoesNotMatter) {
                final HomeBloc homeBloc = BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context);
                final ProfilePageBloc profileBloc = BlocProvider.of<ProfilePageBloc>(context);
                print("homeBloc: ${homeBloc.toString()}");
                print("profileBloc: ${profileBloc.toString()}");


              return Center(
                child: Text("Doesn't really matter"),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

and the output I get is

```
homeBloc: Instance of 'HomeBloc'
profileBloc: null
```

I expected `profileBloc` to be instantiated like `homeBloc` was.

This makes me completely unable to continue development. I have no idea why it's like that.
The best thing is, it worked *a few times*, but I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that 'ProfilePageBloc` wasn't instantiated because an assertion was failing in its constructor. 
Code I've provided in the quesiton wasn't enough to solve it.

[More info here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/750)